# How to approximate the following equation?

Tags: approximation, nonlinear-dynamics

We have the following equation $$1-\frac{h}{u}=\frac{R}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}.$$ Let $r=R-1$ then show that for small $r,h,u$ the equation reduces to $$h+ru-\frac{u^3}{2}\approx0.$$

My Attempt: On squaring both sides we get $$1+\frac{h^2}{u^2}-\frac{2h}{u}=\frac{R^2}{u^2+1}$$
$$\implies \color{red}{u^4}+u^2h^2+h^2-2hu^3-\color{red}{2hu}=(r^2+1+\color{red}{2r})u^2$$ If keep only $$u^4-2hu=2ru^2$$ Then I can get $$ru+h-\frac{u^3}{2}\approx 0.$$ But why does this work?

Answer (score 1):

I think there need to be further assumptions on the relative rates at which $r$ and $h$ approach zero.

We're tasked with developing the solutions for $u$ of the quartic equation
$$u^4 -2hu^3 +(h^2-2r-r^2) u^2 -2hu +h^2=0$$
as series in $r$ and $h$. But we don't know the relative rates at which $r$ and $h$ approach zero, so let's suppose that

$$\begin{align}r&\propto t^{\mathrm{ord}\,r}(1+o(1))\\
h&\propto t^{\mathrm{ord}\,h}(1+o(1))\\
u&\propto t^{\mathrm{ord}\,u}(1+o(1))\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Then for $u^4$, $-2hu$, and $-2ru^2$ to be the lowest order vanishing terms in the quartic polynomial, calculations involving the [Newton polygon](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Polya/07468342.di020774.02p0260v.pdf) imply that we must have
$$\begin{align}
0<\mathrm{ord}\,u &=\mathrm{ord}\,h-\mathrm{ord}\,r\\
0<\mathrm{ord}\,r &<2(\mathrm{ord}\,h)\\
0<\mathrm{ord}\,h &<2(\mathrm{ord}\,r)\text{,}
\end{align}$$
e.g.,
$$\begin{align}\mathrm{ord}\,r&=2&\mathrm{ord}\,h&=3&\mathrm{ord}\,u&=1\text{.}
\end{align}$$